# How to get a API with email

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to figure out how to email a person with python and I'm wondering on how to get the api-key.

```
from socketlabs.injectionapi import SocketLabsClient
from socketlabs.injectionapi.message.bulkmessage import BulkMessage
from socketlabs.injectionapi.message.bulkrecipient import BulkRecipient
from socketlabs.injectionapi.message.emailaddress import EmailAddress

# Your SocketLabs ServerId and Injection API key
client = SocketLabsClient(10000, "YOUR-API-KEY");

message = BulkMessage()

message.plain_text_body = "This is the body of my message sent to %%Name%%"
message.html_body = "<html>This is the HtmlBody of my message sent to %%Name%%</html>"
message.subject = "Sending a test message"
message.from_email_address = EmailAddress("from@example.com")
```

can someone tell me how to get a api-key or what it is?

Answer (score 0):

I Know How to send emails with Python i can help you with that

```
    import smtplib
    import socket
    email='Your Email Address'
    password='Your Password'
    
    
    def sendMail(to, message):
        #you can replace gmail with type of email you use(outlook, yahoo, etc) but port number(587) is same
        try:
            server=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        except socket.gaierror:
            print('No Internet')
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        # if ur login account is gmail then please turn on lesssecure app access at myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps
        server.login(email, password)
        server.sendmail('Your Email', to, message)
    
    
    sendMail('example@outlook.com', 'message')
```

Comment: i recently made a software called emailer for myself with this code it works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

You have to sign up to socketlabs. Then only you will get an API key for sending the automated email.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.